# What happens if you declare an SQLite column PRIMARY KEY + UNIQUE?

Tags: sqlite

SQLite's documentation says:

> A UNIQUE constraint is similar to a PRIMARY KEY constraint, except that a single table may have any number of UNIQUE constraints.

What I'm wondering is, if I declare something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE);
```

Does SQLite create two indexes or one? Is the behavior different if I'm not using the rowid (i.e. if the column was `id TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE`)?

I realize the simplest thing to do is just remove `UNIQUE` but I'm curious what effect this will have.

Comment: FWIW, I discovered that this creates an `sqlite_autoindex` which subtly alters the normal behaviour. To begin with, it seemed to make no difference, but I then started to find that I was randomly unable to select certain rows by primary key. I have not been able to work out exactly why this is, so it would still be good to get a proper answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

When you define a primary key it will be unique, no need to define another index for unique column.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The point of primary keys is so that they are unique for any given row.

Meaning you can choose one or more fields to be a primary key, but a single field doesn't have to be unique.

Unique on the other hand has to be unique for the specified fields.
So it's more like a constraint you are placing.

Given this example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user2domain (
    userID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    domainID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID, domainID),
    UNIQUE(userID, domainID) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
)
```

You don't actually have to specify the unique constraint as the primary key would cover the same fields.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user2domain (
    userID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    domainID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID, domainID)
)

-- add this way
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user2domain(userID, domainID) VALUES(@userID, @domainID)
```

This would be enough.

Use the Unique constraint when you absolutely feel like any fields
must be unique but not necessarily a row identifier.

The expected behaviour is overwriting. Primary is of a higher order precedence.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It's not a matter of whether you *should* do it, but rather of what exactly happens if you do.

Comment: Nothing happens. Depends on the implementation of sqlite but usually  IsPrimaryKeyIndex(pIdx) ? SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY 
                            : SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE
, so it just creates one key.

Comment: No, that is clearly wrong, because `UNIQUE` will create an `sqlite_autoindex`. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Can you replicate this behaviour? I have the latest sqlite3 and I have tried a number of tests and no effect. Maybe there is a bug or artefact that happens when you have both of them on the same key but I haven't been able to cause any strange behaviour yet. If so we could flag it to the sqlite team to bug fix it as the expected behaviour is that primary key overwrites the unique key behaviour in this case.

Comment: I was never able to fully diagnose the problem. Removing the UNIQUE contraint fixed it, but I never discovered why, so I just redesigned the program to avoid it. Amyway, the reelevant point here is that your answer does not address any of the points raised in the question. The OP isn't asking for a tutorial on usage - they want to understand the underlying mechanics.

Comment: Like I said, The underlying mechanics are that its order of presendence and its overwritten.

Comment: does primary key for two columns ignores data with either one of the column when it is duplicate ? or consider two of the columns at the same time to be duplicate ?
I know when you give a unique index specifying two columns, it looks for keys when two of the keys to be unique combinely.

Comment: primary and unique columns are different, as you might have more than one column that creates a primary column. But together they have to be unique.